# Using PayPal Express Checkout with ecommerce site- item limit?

Tags: paypal

I'm integrating PayPal Express Checkout in to an ecommerce site and I've come across this in the API Field List-

> L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm L_NAMEn (deprecated)
>
> Item name. This field is
>   required when L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORYm is passed. You can
>   specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9,
>   inclusive, and m specifies the list item within the payment; except
>   for digital goods, which supports single payments only. These
>   parameters must be ordered sequentially beginning with 0 (for example
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAME0, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAME1).

Does this mean I can't have more than 10 items listed in my basket at checkout?

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if there is another option for submitting items to the checkout... The reason that I say this is because its got (deprecated) on the end of it.. This means that there is another option available to use that is more current. The L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEmL_NAMEn is still usable for backwards compatibility but usually when something is deprecated they have implemented another method for handling that value.. Sorry not much help but maybe that will point you in the right direction..

Comment: Thank you, but I think it means that L_NAMEn is deprecated but L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm isn't, even though when downloading the latest NVP I can find on the PayPal site they are using L_NAMEn... I'm finding the whole PayPal documentation/code samples/site structure to be a complete unintelligible mess so far!

Comment: Yeah it is a real big mess. I went through major headaches on my last project working with the paypal IPN.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one- I thought I was being an idiot for all the trouble I've been having but seeing a big company like PayPal have broken links, out of date samples etc. has shocked me! I might look in to Google Checkout for my next project.

Comment: Surprisingly alot of the documentation for Google checkout can be worked around figuring out Paypal... I found their information to be more helpful for PayPal than PayPal's own documentation..